# How can I recover the users with whom a user chatted recently from a MySQL db?

Tags: mysql, sql, chat

I would like to ask some help in a query I came across.

Basically, I have three tables:

1. 'users', stores all the data of a user in the db, the fields are:

   - usr_id -> is the id of the user, primary key;
   - usr_profile_photo_id, a foreign key that references a profile photo filename in a 'files' table where all the names of the files of a user are stored (in this case the foreign key references the profile photo filename);
   - usr_name -> the name of the user;
   - usr_surname -> the surname;
2. 'files', stores files of a user, the fields are:

   - fil_usr_id -> foreign key that references a user in the 'users' table;
   - fil_uid -> the referenced file id (this is the field referenced by the 'usr_profile_photo_id');
   - fil_name -> the name of the file (e.g. user154241profile.png, user163451profile.png, etc.);
3. 'chat', which stores all the chat messages of the users, the fields are:

   - id -> the primary key, identifies in a univocal way a chat message;
   - chat_from -> foreign key that references the id of the user that wrote the chat message;
   - chat_fromname -> is the name together with the surname (e.g. "John Smith", "Mary Smith", etc.) of the user that wrote the chat message;
   - chat_to -> foreign key that references the id of the user to whom the chat message is adressed;
   - chat_toname -> the complete name of that 'to' user (like chat_fromname);
   - chat_sent -> the date of the message (DATE MySQL type);

What I need to do is to recover all the users with whom a user has recently chatted, and I do it like so:

```
SELECT U.usr_id,
       C.chat_fromname,
       F.fil_uid
FROM users AS U chat AS C,
     files AS F
WHERE C.chat_from = U.usr_id
  AND F.fil_uid = U.usr_profile_photo_id
  AND U.usr_id IN
    (
     SELECT G.chat_from
     FROM chat AS G
     WHERE G.chat_to = 1
     UNION SELECT D.chat_to
     FROM chat AS D
     WHERE D.chat_from = 1
    )
GROUP BY U.usr_id,
         C.chat_fromname,
         F.fil_uid
ORDER BY C.chat_sent DESC;
```

The problem is that the query doesn't seem to behave as I expect, cause it returns the users a user chatted with recently, but not ordered by the date of the chat message sent (chat_sent column), seems like MySQL is ignoring the order by clause, or maybe am I wrong in something?

What should I do to retrieve those recently users ordered in the correct way?

EDIT: possible better solution:

```
SELECT chat_from, chat_fromname
FROM chat AS C
WHERE C.to = 1
GROUP BY chat_from, chat_fromname
ORDER BY MAX(C.chat_sent) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Here I recover the last 10 users that WROTE a message to the user (so the user is the receiver).

Then something like:

```
SELECT U.usr_id, F.fil_uid
FROM users AS U, files AS F
WHERE F.fil_uid = U.usr_profile_photo_id AND (
-- dinamically built based on the previous result.
U.usr_id = 1 OR 
U.usr_id = 2 OR 
U.usr_id = 3 OR 
U.usr_id = 4 OR 
U.usr_id = 5 OR 
U.usr_id = 6 OR 
U.usr_id = 7 OR 
U.usr_id = 8 OR 
U.usr_id = 9 OR 
U.usr_id = 10);
```

But the problem here is that I recover only the users that WROTE to the user, I hope to be clear... What if the user wrotes something to the user 8 for example (so the user 8 is the chat_to receiver)?

Comment: `users AS U chat AS C` is a typo?

Comment: Unrelated, but you shouldn't be using a subquery here. It's terribly slow. Break the user_id out into a separate query and just put a comma separated list of ids in this query

Comment: @hjpotter92, users AS U chat AS C is a typo? They are aliases.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert, are advising me something like this? See my EDIT:

Comment: specify **all** the columns you want to order the result set by in the 'order by' clause. e.g order by u.usr_id, c.chat_sent.

Comment: @user3019105 yes, that's what I mean. The better syntax is `U.usr_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8)` though. Depending on the size of the database, it could literally be millions of times faster to run the query this way, compared to a subquery.